# My background image for my controller index view is not loading in rails 4 app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have a welcome controller, and a welcome.css.scss layout.  In the welcome layout there is this code:

```
body {
background-image: url("/assets/images/sampleimage.jpeg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In assets/images I have a picture called sampleimage.jpeg which I want to be my background for the welcome index view.

I have all of the above, but I get neither a a background image or an error message.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using SCSS, let me give you some ideas...

--

**Asset Paths**

Firstly, what you need is [`asset_path` helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url), allowing Rails to call the assets regardless of whether they are in the standard "asset pipeline", or in the precompiled "static" assets area

The immediate issue you have is that you're calling a naked `url` on your `background-image` property. This will not call the file you need, as since the path is relative, it cannot be called (try accessing `/assets` from your browser)

The way to do this is as follows:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss
body {
   background: {
      image: asset-url("sampleimage.jpeg");
      repeat: no-repeat;
   }
}
```

The `asset-url` path is possible because of how the SCSS/SASS elements of the Rails asset pipeline [preprocesses](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) your asset request

Comment: It still gives an error "could not find logical path" and "couldn't find file 'sampleimage.jpeg'" It also says to resolve sprocket issues.

Comment: Sprockets::FileNotFound at /

couldn't find file 'sampleimage.jpeg' (in /app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss.erb)

Comment: raise FileNotFound, "couldn't find file '#{logical_path}'"

Comment: don't put .erb at the end of the file - are you including & installing the sprockets gem?

Comment: It was only there a minute I just tried it once, and yes I just double checked.